# Macruby get an object to notify AppDelegate when its completed a task

Tags: http, macruby

I am super new to Macruby and I'm trying to write a small app that sends post data to an api and then displays the response in text field.

I have gotten as far as collecting, sending the data and having the response output to the console using this gist: https://gist.github.com/alloy/885125

What I want to know is how do I get the download object to notify the AppDelegate, either via an event or some other mechanism, that its completed so I can collects its response and add it to the text field object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the supplied gist as a separate object that calls the main class when its finished I moved all the methods into the main AppDelegate class and had it delegate to itself once the post methods had finished.